# What is the use of vectors for forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, coulombs-law

i am studying the coulomb's law.then i encounter the formula for force between charges i.e $F=k q1q2/r^2$. They represent it with its vector form. now my question what is the use of that vector form. why we need it. if we have a normal coulomb  formula why we represent it in vector form.what is the thing we  cannot do with coulomb's normal law but we can easily do that thing with its vector form.
They also do the same with gravitation law and after giving its normal formula they represent it in vector form. i don't understand what is the purpose behind it. why  it is important to represent laws like gravitation and coulomb's law in vector form and what is this vector form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use vectors to describe velocity/force/etc instead of treating magnitude and direction as separate values?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234246/)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253009/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132237/25301 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262521/25301, probably others.

Answer (score 1):

When studying the interaction of several forces, in different directions, it is an easy way to keep track of the direction each of these forces are in.

Also mathematically vectors tend to be very easy to work complex problems with since they natively support actions that appear naturally in many cases such as the dot product, vector product, ...

Answer (score 0):

The **magnitudes** of both Coulomb's and Newton's laws are given by

$$ F_C = k\frac{Q q}{r^2} , \qquad  F_N = \frac{G M m}{r^2}. $$

Now ask yourself what are these statements really telling you. In their current forms they are simply numbers or you could say both $F_C$ and $F_N$ in their current form are a measure of the *strength* of either attraction/repulsion between two charged particles **or** it measures the strength which two particles are gravitationally attracted to each other.

In what **direction** are these forces directed? This is answered by using a vector equation. Please see image below (kindly borrowed from Wikipedia.)

[image]

You might like to look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law).

Answer (score 0):

Coulomb's law deals with charge-charge interaction based on action at a point concept  It means forces acting between the two charges are action_reaction pair.Vector form of Coulomb's law clearly explains the action_reaction pair.